# SQL Count on JOIN query is taking forever to execute?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run count query on a 2 table join. e_amazing_client table is having million entries/rows and m_user has just 50 rows BUT count query is taking forever!

```
SELECT COUNT(`e`.`id`) AS `count` 
FROM `e_amazing_client` AS `e` 
LEFT JOIN `user` AS `u` ON `e`.`cx_hc_user_id` = `u`.`id` 
WHERE ((`e`.`date_created` >= '2018-11-11') AND (`e`.`date_created` >= '2018-11-18')) AND (`e`.`id` >= 1)
```

I don't know what is wrong with this query?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  A count in a `left join` query doesn't usually refer only to the first table.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm guessing that this is sufficient:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM e_amazing_client e
WHERE e.date_created >= '2018-11-11' AND e.id >= 1;
```

If `user` has only 50 rows, I doubt it is creating duplicates.  The comparisons on `date_created` are redundant.

For this query, try creating an index on `e_amazing_client(date_created, id)`.

Comment: Still it's taking too much time to execute!

Comment: actually i have filters and each filter returns different records/rows so i want to count that rows. And the above query is when the table loads at first it will return all the rows.

Comment: @DojoDev . . . If this query is too slow, you need to reset your expectations.  The conditions that you have require scanning either the table or the index -- and that is going to take some tme.

Comment: Why this `SELECT COUNT(e.id) AS `count` FROM e_amazing_client as e` query take less time than the above one? Even the above has index?

Comment: i need this count for pagination. Where i am showing filtered records and total records returned.

Comment: @DojoDev . . . The query with no `where` clause should use the primary key index, which is presumably smaller than any index that has to have multiple columns.  I don't think there are other optimizations that MySQL makes on `count(*)`; however, you might also have a query cache that speeds things up.

Comment: but we are also using id (PK) in where clause!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`e`.`id`) AS `count` 
FROM `e_amazing_client` AS `e` 
LEFT JOIN `user` AS `u` ON `e`.`cx_hc_user_id` = `u`.`id` 
WHERE ((`e`.`date_created` >= '2018-11-11') AND (`e`.`date_created` <= '2018-11-18')) AND (`e`.`id` >= 1)
```

to check between dates?  
Also, do you really need

```
AND (`e`.`id` >= 1)
```

If `id` is what an id is usually in a table, is there a case to be `<1`?

Comment: No that was by mistake but still it's taking forever to execute.

Comment: @DojoDev maybe *forever* is just the usual amount of time for cases involving millions of records. If the results you get are correct then the only thing you can do is create the proper indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is pulling ALL records on/after 2018-11-11 because your WHERE clause is ID >= 1  You have no clause in there for a specific user.  You also had in your original query based on a date of >= 2018-11-18.  You MAY have meant you only wanted the count WITHIN the week 11/11 to 11/18 where the sign SHOULD have been >= 11-11 and <= 11-18.

As for the count, you are getting ALL people (assuming no entry has an ID less than 1) and thus a count within that date range.  If you want it per user as you indicated you need to group by the cx_hc_user_id (user) column to see who has the most, or make the user part of the WHERE clause to get one person.

```
SELECT 
      e.cx_hc_user_id,
      count(*) countPerUser
   from
      e_amazing_client e
   WHERE 
          e.date_created >= '2018-11-11'
      AND e.date_created <= '2018-11-18'
   group by
      e.cx_hc_user_id
```

You can order by the count descending to get the user with the highest count, but still not positive what you are asking.

Comment: actually I have filters and each filter returns different records/rows so i want to count that rows. And the above query is when the table loads at first it will return all the rows

Comment: i need this count for pagination. Where i am showing filtered records and total records returned.